# How to have the output of Grep same as pattern from a file?

Tags: linux, design-patterns, grep

Good day.

I used Grep to extract readings from a file according to pattern of an ID file.

```
grep -w -f idFile.txt readingFile.txt
```

The ouput of Grep I obtained was:

```
F47807  0.00    0.00    8.30
R02218  0.00    0.00    2.07
W74941  0.00    0.00    5.70
C15915  0.00    0.00    3.63
C16638  0.00    0.39    8.82
C16979  0.00    0.39    2.59
```

Let's say the ID file is:

```
W74941
F47807
C15915
R02218
C16638
C16979
```

I would like to have the Grep output same pattern as the ID file like below:

```
W74941  0.00    0.00    5.70
F47807  0.00    0.00    8.30
C15915  0.00    0.00    3.63
R02218  0.00    0.00    2.07
C16638  0.00    0.39    8.82
C16979  0.00    0.39    2.59
```

I tried with couple of Grep option but I failed to obtain what I want. Thus, could the community kindly please gives me some advice how can I do that?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this with grep only, but if you make use of a bit of bash, you can do this:

```
for line in $(cat idFile.txt)
    do grep "$line" readingFile.txt
done
```

This will go over the readingFile once for each id though, so if performance a worry, this won't help you.

Edit: Note that this assumes that the id's contain no spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I knew the Grep ables to read and parse directly from file. The little bit of Bash really helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of `awk` you can do something like this -

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$0
    next 
} 
($1 in a) { 
    print a[$1] 
}' <(grep -w -f idFile.txt readingFile.txt) idfile
```

#### Explaination:

- `awk` is combination of `/pattern/ {action}` statements. Our first pattern `NR==FNR` ensures that our action is performed only on the first file passed to the awk (grep output in our case).
- Our `action` for this is to store it in an array.
- Once the first file is completed, our pattern will become false and second `pattern-action` statement will come in force.
- Second `pattern-action` statements checks to see if first entry of your idfile is present in the array. If it is, it prints it. As a result you get the output based on the sequence found in idfile.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. If I may, could you please explain a bit the Awk codes above?

Comment: @KJLim Added the explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you so much. It is helpful for those who like to understand more about awk function. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner should work with your grep output and idfile:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a&&$0=a[$1]'
```

complete line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a&&$0=a[$1]' <(grep -w -f idFile.txt readingFile.txt) idfile
```